# SDK to Encrypt Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, security, core-data, sqlcipher

I am working on encrypting the core data files in my app. I found solutions like SQLCipher and encrypted-core-data sdks in git hub as best and most used sdks to secure the data that are open source. But I have seen articles that show case these sdks consuming significantly more cpu.

I went through the Data Protection capability provided by Apple as well, but in my case I can't use it because I need my app to access the core data even when the device is locked.

I know that encrypting and decrypting the data does come with performance problems, but I would like to know if there are any commercial paid sdks that do the encryption with least burden on cpu.

Comment: Since iOS 8.3, all application data are encrypted unless being shared intentionally, and all accesses are prohibited. That is why raw file browsers and jailbreaking all became history.

Comment: Can you provide a reference article showing the increased CPU use?

Comment: @StephenLombardo https://www.pgs-soft.com/securing-your-app-with-encrypted-core-data/

Answer (score 0):

> But I have seen articles that show case these sdks consuming more cpu.

Of course. If you encrypt your data, you're doing more work. In addition to whatever your app normally does with its data, you add the work of encrypting and decrypting that data. More work will require more CPU time.

Comment: Of course I know that.. But I saw significant difference with sqlcipher. I want to know if there are any sdks that consume less processing power compared to sql cipher..